# Display non formatted dates in VCS log

Tags: intellij-idea, version-control

How do I replace formatted dates with their non-formatted / standard counterpart?

[image]

Standard:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply uncheck `Use pretty formatting` under `Appearence & Behavior > System Settings > Date Formats`.

[image]